# Typing lag on Signal Desktop on Ubuntu 22.04 until I move my mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I have been using signal desktop for 6 month, and since a week my typing lag until I move my mouse, it is really weird, the cursor is not blinking neither until I move my mouse and then freeze again.

my env :
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Dell XPS
signal-desktop : 6.13.0

Comment: How did you install signal? Is it a snap or deb or some other package? Are you typing in a single 1:1 conversation or a large group chat?

Comment: I install it by snap, and it appears on any kind of conversation, it feels like moving the mouse "validate the input".
I delete the all application and re-install it, doesn't solve anything, same problem even if I lost my hystoric.